# Krovetz stemming alogrithm ( KStemming) help needed

Tags: algorithm, solr, filter, stemming

Could you please explain me the algorithm for Krovetz stemming alogrithm ( Kstemming) , i want to know how its working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/computing/research/stemming/general/krovetz.htm) and his paper [Viewing morphology as aninference process](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:4F9cqY-PE-0J%3alexicalresearch.com/sigir-93.pdf%20&hl=tr&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgSqGWyNU8Suqt0ZoOCOTBO1kl8W54gRUeGCdLoX-VWQvjvlF7BbC4ZouSu-DFIredD8UTxSiXGVR0ftOBt_Mf9aCMHiRGXeQcsCWPOEOO2HD9Ke73_cIN9hdyCsUSj-3Wuf2kG&sig=AHIEtbT1jRdBcDn6xVuaKQz-rr1ApiC_aA).

You can also find some other useful documents and papers below.They also talk about Krovetz stemming algorithm.

- [Stemming Algorithms for Information Retrieval and
  Question/Answer Systems](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3ahHvEa11QaKMJ%3awww.psychology.adelaide.edu.au/personalpages/staff/simondennis/DSTO2.pdf%20&hl=tr&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjd_xRl_rUjzY8dbVX0VczZrXW9bBOKeWATguwcrAQC9oSzEcUaxFZ2bDhrBMqX7vCXnIYzGxYVw6W-IcinY5Fh21QODWWw3PTI_ts-mFTKApzgb59X_i0jTXjHb2Y74vwVt5PQ&sig=AHIEtbTk0YiQ_qy7zXZRSKUPlpfvs4blDQ&pli=1)
- [Stemming in Bangla](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:22IxvCS0qAcJ%3acrblp.bracu.ac.bd/nlpcourse/report/stemming_report.pdf%20&hl=tr&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiGppXH53iLIFPukxIq3Q17n5tcKOAk05Nmvui4gxFf3hQUBRtMczXcqlIaUtwScQScTwn5RKAPUY3i0k2cnZ5obUaMvdiBRxd_r0prBFLlFAvKDX0Eq2L3CeQCrYoxMrJDjIWl&sig=AHIEtbRtZXB99vyOZRdcP9_gi7uDMEUR0w)
- [A Comparative Study of Stemming Algorithms](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:98J8jZlC-pYJ%3aijcta.com/documents/volumes/vol2issue6/ijcta2011020632.pdf%20&hl=tr&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgREGDHo2pvnoDqXxg4cXFUVRzj_7Qy2Qsiy3LyqHGNPmP7hoA8qjdPhqdocRH3jViq1EyUeruTZGm7CeT4Xlx10gWOimzl5yMXxcGp9u2YCCXH4N0SeoyqH30IMEM7Zt6znmeQ&sig=AHIEtbRRMByROpWAh-q6uL1CVq2TqIF5uQ)